# If $\frac d{dx} f(x,y)>0$, can I claim that $f(x,y)$ is increasing with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, monotone-functions, implicit-function-theorem

I have an implicit equation $f(x,y)=0$; computing the derivatives, I see that $\frac d{dx} f(x,y)>0$ while $\frac d{dy} f(x,y)$ maybe positive, or negative.

> ***Question***. Is this data sufficient to claim that $f(x,y)$ is increasing with respect to $x$?

Comment: Depends on the shape of the domain.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Thanks. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: What do you *mean* by the notation $\frac{d}{dx}$ (as opposed to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$), to begin with? If you're on a curve $y=y(x)$ implicitly defined by the equation $f(x,y)=0$, then obviously $\frac{d}{dx} f(x,y) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x,y(x)) = \frac{d}{dx} 0 = 0$, so it can't be positive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to talk about whether it is increasing with respect to $x$, you need to let $y$ be given and fixed and then you look at the partial derivative with respect to $x$ for this fixed $y$. In your case, since you have computed the derivative and it is positive, you conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing with respect to $x$ for every fixed $y$.

Comment: If so, then, for a typical function that is continuous and well-defined over the real domain, does this imply that if one of the derivatives, the other one should be positive as well? I mean the function should be increasing wrt both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This is in general not correct. Consider the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+1}{y^2+1}$. This is increasing with respect to $x$ and decreasing with respect to $y$.

Comment: But your example is a 2D function, my question is about an implicit equation.

Comment: You can just look at $\frac{x^2}{y^2+1}=0$.

Comment: I plot your equation, but, there is no answer, implying that the function is nonzero unless $x=0$. (I use ContourPlot in Mathematica)

Comment: Therefore it is monotonically increasing in $x$ and monotonically decreasing in $y$.